# Filling a numpy array with numpy arrays objects using a boolean mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of objects like this one:

```
a = np.array([[None, None],
              [None, None]], dtype=object)
```

and a mask:

```
mask = np.array([[True , False],
                 [False, True ]], dtype=object)
```

I want to replace the values of `a` indexed by the `mask` with an array like this one:

```
element = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

So I can get:

```
a = np.array([[np.array([1, 2, 3]), None               ],
              [None               , np.array([1, 2, 3])]], dtype=object)
```

I have tried this

```
a[mask].fill(element)
a[mask] = element
np.putmask(a, mask, element)
```

but the element is always considered as an array instead of a random object.

Actually, I have found a way to make it work, but not very efficient (I need to do it many times with a big array):

```
full = np.empty_like(a, dtype=object)
f.fill(element)
np.putmask(a, mask, full)
```

Is there a more direct way to do this?

Comment: Why do you think the working version is not efficient?  Compared to what?  Assigning arrays to elements of an object array is always tricky, because `broadcasting` gets in the way.  The fast numpy methods apply primarily to numeric dtypes.  Object dtype requires list like processing (and may actually be slower).